# Updating multiple values of a Azure DevOps variable group from another variable group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I have a requirement which is as follows:

Variable Group A, has 7 set of key=value pairs
Variable Group B, has 7 set of key=value pairs.

In both cases keys are the same, values are only different.

I am asking from the user, the value of be injected in variable group B, user provides me the variable group A name.

Code snippet to perform such update is as below:

```
export reference_env="Variable Group A"
export target_env="Variable Group B"

values=(addressSearchBaseUrl addressSearchSubscriptionKey cacheUrl calendarApiUrl checkoutBffApiUrl cpCode)

groupId=$(az pipelines variable-group list --group-name "${reference_env}" | jq -r '. [].id')

#grab groupid for further checks later on.

az_create_options=()

for ptr in "${values[@]}"
do
    result=$(
      az pipelines variable-group list --group-name "${Variable Group ${reference_env}" | jq '.[0].variables.'${ptr}'.value'
    )
    printf "%s\t%s\t%d\n" "$ptr" "$result" $?

if [[ "$ptr" = "calendarApiUrl"  ]]
then
   echo "INF: Updating $ptr with new value"
   result="https://noname-api.platform.test.com.au/marketing/calendar/v1/AvailableDates/market1/"
   insertString=";rev=${target_env}"
   lookingfor="v1"
   result=$(echo $result| sed s/"${lookingfor}"/"${insertString}"/g)
   echo $result
fi


az_create_options+=("$ptr"="$result" )
done

declare -p az_create_options

az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id 1202 --name "${target_env}" "${az_create_options[@]}"
```

However, when I run this, I get error as below:
Note: I have masked the values in light of IP but error is the same.

```
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: addressSearchBaseUrl="https://xxxxxxxxxx" addressSearchSubscriptionKey="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" cacheUrl="qqqqqqqqqqqqq" calendarApiUrl=tttttttttttttttt checkoutBffApiUrl="sssssssssssssssss" cpCode="333333"
```

Can someone guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly used update command:

```
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id
                                            --name
                                            [--detect {false, true}]
                                            [--new-name]
                                            [--org]
                                            [--project]
                                            [--prompt-value {false, true}]
                                            [--secret {false, true}]
                                            [--subscription]
                                            [--value]
```

`name` is a vairable name. So if you want to update each variable you need to update it one by one.

Comment: Yep, correct, my bad. I realized that. I however, don't know how to refer to two arrays...

Comment: You may change slighlty the way progarm works. I mean you have array with variable names. So make a loop and there fecth value from the first variable gorup and in next step set a value in another variable group.